# Concatenate field and string

Tags: concatenation, fastreport

I'm trying to concatenate a field with as string on FastReport and it's giving me all sorts of error.

My last attempts were:

```
[IIF(<fmRelOFtbTemp2."GROUP"> = '02', <fmRelOFtbTemp2."Weight"> & 'kg', '')]
[IIF(<fmRelOFtbTemp2."GROUP"> = '02', <fmRelOFtbTemp2."Weight"> + 'kg', '')]
[IIF(<fmRelOFtbTemp2."GROUP"> = '02', <fmRelOFtbTemp2."Weight"> & "kg", '')]
[IIF(<fmRelOFtbTemp2."GROUP"> = '02', <fmRelOFtbTemp2."Weight"> + "kg", '')]
```

It only works if I use the field alone:

```
[IIF(<fmRelOFtbTemp2."GROUP"> = '02', <fmRelOFtbTemp2."Weight">, '')]
```

Comment: What are the errors?